# Start and close UINavigationView programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have many options about displaying views if user taps on row in tableview (3 options).
I start new ViewController like this:

```
 ImageViewNIB *dest = [[ImageViewNIB alloc] init];
        [self presentViewController:dest animated:YES completion:nil];
```

And when it shows up I'd like to close it by clicking button. I shows new view from NIB file.

```
@interface ImageViewNIB : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *close;


@end



#import "ImageViewNIB.h"

@interface ImageViewNIB ()

@end

@implementation ImageViewNIB

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (IBAction)backBtnUserClicked:(id)object {

    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        NSLog(@"KONCZE");
    }];
}
@end
```

And view from nib:

[image]

Everything is started and created programmatically also the UINavigationBar and button inside it. Button in NaviationBar is UIBarButtonItem type but I've connect it with IB with method in ".M" class. It does not show NSLOG and the view doesn't close when it is taped. How to make this segue programmatically instead of STORYBOARD?

Comment: What is a `UINavigationView`? It's not in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/search/?q=UINavigationView).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have an `UINavigationController`. Therefore you should send the dismiss method to self:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    NSLog(@"KONCZE");
}];
```